# HighChart - Save Image into myChart.png file

Tags: node.js, highcharts, png

I am trying to save the highchart graph into an image (.png) file using node.js

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d
>   '{"infile":{"title": {"text": "Steep Chart"}, "xAxis": {"categories":
>   ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]}, "series": [{"data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}}'
>   127.0.0.1:7801 -o mychart.png

Using above curl, I can able to get the image. I am trying to have it using node.

In this example, to save the highchart image to a file, what changes to be made to get the .png file as my output?

```js
//Include the exporter module
const exporter = require('highcharts-export-server');

//Export settings 
var exportSettings = {
    fileName  : 'myChart',     // The name of the chart
    file      : 'myChart.png', // The name of the chart plus its extension
    type      : 'png',
 options: {
        title: {
            text: 'My Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'line',
                data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 2]
            }
        ]
    }
};

//Set up a pool of PhantomJS workers
exporter.initPool();

//Perform an export
/*
    Export settings corresponds to the available CLI arguments described
    above.
*/
exporter.export(exportSettings, function (err, res) {
    //The export result is now in res.
    //If the output is not PDF or SVG, it will be base64 encoded (res.data).
    //If the output is a PDF or SVG, it will contain a filename (res.filename).

 console.log('res : ' + res.data + ' : ' + res.filename);
 console.log('err : ' + err);
    //Kill the pool when we're done with it, and exit the application
    exporter.killPool();
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me:

```
   //Include the exporter module
    const exporter = require('./node_modules/highcharts-export-server');
    var settings = require('./settings'); // exporting options


    //Set up a pool of PhantomJS workers
    exporter.initPool();

    //Perform an export
    /*
        Export settings corresponds to the available CLI arguments described
        above.
    */
    exporter.export(settings, function(err, res) {


      //If the output is not PDF or SVG, it will be base64 encoded (res.data).
      //If the output is a PDF or SVG, it will contain a filename (res.filename).
      //Kill the pool when we're done with it, and exit the application

      require("fs").writeFile("out.png", res.data, 'base64', function(err) {
        exporter.killPool();
        process.exit(1);
        console.log(err);
      });

      console.log(err);

    });
```

I'm using file system object (`fs`) to translate it from base64 encoding and save it as a file. `exproter.killPool` and `process.exit` are preformed in callback function executed after saving the file ends (or fails).